# How can I find the ActiveX ClassID of a COM object?

Tags: com, activex

I have developed an integration for an ActiveX control. The problem is that during development, a new build was created, which means there is a different ActiveX Class ID.

Is there any way to determine the Program ID and ActiveX class ID of a COM object without contacting the developer?

Researching online, I found reference to OLE/COM Object Viewer, but there doesn't seem to be any way to do a search outside of expanding every node.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: You can open the DLL using COM/OLE Viewer and browse its type library there. You will see the `CLSID`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly see the CLSIDs if you have a type library for the COM server and can look at it with Oleview.exe.  You don't have to look at every node in the tree, only the **coclass** nodes are relevant.

You however cannot see the ProgId in the type library.  One way to find it is to use the Edit + Find command in Regedit.exe, paste the CLSID guid you got from the type library.

You get everything when you use SysInternals' ProcMon utility.  Start it up, then register the server with Regsvr32.exe.  You'll see the trace of the program writing the registry keys in the ProcMon output.

Comment: Dear @Hans passant Please tell me how to find the class id of an ActiveX make in vb6?